# PDF export not using specified font on Reporting Services Report

Tags: visual-studio, pdf, reporting-services, fonts, report

I developed a report for Reporting Services 2008 R2 that utilizes a specific font. Google Font EB Garamond. I installed that font on the developer machine, and everything works fine on visual studio: preview, exporting to PDF and etc. But when I deployed the report to the server and ran from the reporting services web interface it didn't work.

My first thought: the font needs to be installed on the server as well. Did that, and that fixed the live preview, but the export to PDF (which is what I need) didn't work, it used ARIAL instead for all the text.

I checked the embedded fonts on the exported PDF and there were none, so I figured I needed to restart the service on the server in order for the font to be loaded. Did that, and that worked, now the exported PDF has EB Garamond embedded BUT **it is still using ARIAL for all the text**.

[image]

Don't know what else to check. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you reboot after installing the the server after applying the font. I do not think that SSRS will pick up on fonts unless a full reboot is issued this may be an IIS limitation.

Comment: I did not, but I did restart the SSRS service, which caused the font to be embedded on the PDF. I can't reboot during the day, so if nothing works today I'll reboot tomorrow morning. Thanks. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: I think you have to reboot the server after adding a new font.